# Check a file if the same thing is written 3 times

Tags: python

I'm very new to accessing files. I want to see if the same thing is written 3 times in a text file and if it is replace it with something that is written only one time so it is balanced.

Any idea how I can do that?
Edit: if it is possible only if they are in 2 separate lines in the file
Edit 2 : file example:

```
John-Alex
John-Kyle
John-Ben
Ben-Gary
```

So John in the 3rd line should be replaced by Kyle or Alex or Gary.

Maybe separate everything and if let's say John is found 3 times, then only one of the John found in the file be replaced by Gary, Kyle or Alex as they are in a different line and there is only one of them. So let's say one of the John is replaced by Alex like this:

> ```
> John-Alex
> Alex-Kyle
> John-Ben
> Ben-Gary
> ```

As you can see, John is replaced by Alex and it isn't in the same line as Alex as that would be Alex-Alex and that is not okay.

Comment: Can you provide a file example?

Comment: Not so easy, and a lot of rules are required.
You need a list of names;
What happens if you replace John with Gary and at line 5 you have Gary again?

Comment: So what code have you written to try to solve this?

Comment: @KonekoSama if you're very new to accessing files it might not be so useful to ask questions that require a complex logic. Next time please focus on the goal you want to achieve : a simple question to be introduced to file handling in Python that can serve a nice illustration to the subject.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the code that will check if a line in a file is repeated 3 or more times:

```
names = {}
with open("your_file.txt", "r") as file:
    text = file.read()
    lines = file.readlines()

for line in lines:
    for name in line.split("-"):
        if name in names.keys():
            names[name] += 1
        else:
            names[name] = 1

names_with_count_1 = []
for name, count in names.items():
    if count == 1:
        names_with_count_1.append(name)

for name, count in names.items():
    if count >= 3:
        text.replace(text.find(name, 3), names[names_with_count_1[0]])
        names_with_count_1.remove(names_with_count_1[0])

with open("your_file.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write(text)
```